Recursively include with EF?
I'm trying to recursively include the inner pages of this entity:
public class CatalogPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public string? Caption { get; init; }
    public string? Layout { get; init; }
    public int? RoleId { get; init; }
    public int CatalogPageId { get; init; }
    public int OrderId { get; init; }
    public int IconId { get; init; }
    public ICollection<CatalogPage> Pages { get; init; } = [];
}

I've coded this, but it doesn't include past one level deep:
private static void Load(ICollection<CatalogPage> pages, DbContext db)
{
    foreach (var p in pages)
    {
        db.Entry(p).Collection(x => x.Pages).Load();

        if (p.Pages.Count < 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        Load(p.Pages, db);
    }
}

Usage of the method:
var parentlessPages = await dbContext.Set<CatalogPage>()
    .Include(x => x.Pages)
    .Include(x => x.Items).ThenInclude(x => x.FurnitureItems)
    .Where(x => x.CatalogPageId == -1)
    .ToListAsync();

Load(parentlessPages.SelectMany(x => x.Pages).ToList(), dbContext);

What am I doing wrong?

What do you mean by "recursively", exactly? (I note that recursive algorithms (like DFS/BFS tree traversal) do not work well with EF. Is there a reason you can't use a normal loop?

Your class CatalogPage has some design-flaws... for example, you're using CatalogPageId == -1 - which means you can't have a DB-enforced FK constraint - is there a reason you're not using a nullable-int instead?

This question is similar to: How does Entity Framework work with recursive hierarchies? Include() seems not to work with it. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

EF Core doesn't work well with recursive algorithms. It has no way of using .Include on them.
Instead, retrieve the whole table and recursively add the data into the correct objects using a lookup or dictionary.
var allPages = await dbContext.Set<CatalogPage>()
    .Include(x => x.Items).ThenInclude(x => x.FurnitureItems)
    .ToListAsync();
var lookup = allPages.ToLookup(p => Id);

var parentlessPages = allPages[-1].ToListAsync();
AddChildrenFromLookup(parentlessPages ,lookup);

void AddChildrenFromLookup(IEnumerable<CatalogPage> pages, ILookup<int, CatalogPage> lookup)
{
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        foreach (var childPage in lookup[page.Id])
        {
            page.Pages.Add(childPage);
        }
        AddChildrenFromLookup(page.Pages, lookup);
    }
}

Note that using a flag value -1 doesn't work well with foreign keys. You should use a nullable int? CatalogPageId instead.
